# Getting all posts matching custom post type, taxonomy and category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I currently have the following set up:

- Custom post type called "workshops"
- Within the workshop post type I have a taxonomy called "workshop-status"
- Workshop status subsequently has categories for example "past-event"

I have been using the code below to fetch posts within a particular post type:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'workshops', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    content here...

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

My question is: how can I change this to fetch a post from the past-event category within my custom post type, and custom taxonomy?

My aim is to have multiple page templates and target each category individually.

I have tried changing the arrange to target the category alone, but this did not work. I cannot find an online resource on how to target all aspects.

Comment: Use the below.  You can pass a category id, a list of ids, the category slug, etc.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: You can use the `tax_query` argument in order to fetch posts from several taxonomies. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add the category attribute like so:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'past-event' ) );
```

So in your example case, this would become:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'workshops', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category_name' => 'past-event' ) );
```

You can do a whole load of stuff as detailed in the [code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'workshops',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'workshop-status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'past-event'),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
    )

);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        //do your stuff

    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```